# Execute Potrace command from C# code to convert bitmap image to XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, process, potrace

I am trying to convert my bitmap image to XAML format. Currently I am using Potrace in command Prompt. I will be passing the input file through command prompt only. My problem is that I have to do the same using C# code. I have to call the Potrace process externally and execute it. I tried the following code

```
               Process potrace = new Process
           {
               StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
               {
                   FileName = "potrace.exe",
                   Arguments = "-s -u 1", //SVG
                   RedirectStandardInput = true,
                   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                   RedirectStandardError = Program.IsDebug,
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                   CreateNoWindow = true,
                   WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
               },
               EnableRaisingEvents = false
           };
           StringBuilder svgBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           potrace.OutputDataReceived += (object sender2, DataReceivedEventArgs e2) =>
           {
               svgBuilder.AppendLine(e2.Data);
           };
           if (Program.IsDebug)
           {
               potrace.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender2, DataReceivedEventArgs e2) =>
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e2.Data);
               };
           }
           potrace.Start();
           potrace.BeginOutputReadLine();
           if (Program.IsDebug)
           {
               potrace.BeginErrorReadLine();
           }

           BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(potrace.StandardInput.BaseStream);

           Bitmap.Save(writer.BaseStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
           potrace.StandardInput.WriteLine();
           potrace.WaitForExit();
```

This code gives me an error, the compiler says Program does not exist in this content.! Help me out in solving this problem. If you have any other suggestions, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `C#` version of `Potrace` see [here](https://github.com/XuechaoLee/PoTrace-1).

> C# version of http://potrace.sourceforge.net/ (Peter Selinger) based
>   on http://www.drawing3d.de/ who did the hard job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Some parts of code that did not work are disabled by comments.
This version takes source bmp image from property "Arguments".

```
Process potrace = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\potrace-1.11.win64\potrace.exe",
        Arguments = "C:\\potrace-1.11.win64\\circle.bmp --backend dxf", //DXF
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
   //     RedirectStandardError = Program.IsDebug,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    },
    EnableRaisingEvents = false
};

StringBuilder svgBuilder = new StringBuilder();
potrace.OutputDataReceived += (object sender2, DataReceivedEventArgs e2) =>
{
    svgBuilder.AppendLine(e2.Data);
};
/*
if (Program.IsDebug)
{
    potrace.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender2, DataReceivedEventArgs e2) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e2.Data);
    };
}
 */

potrace.Start();
 /*
  * 
potrace.BeginOutputReadLine();
if (Program.IsDebug)
{
    potrace.BeginErrorReadLine();
}
*/
/*
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(potrace.StandardInput.BaseStream);
// Construct a new image from the GIF file.
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Matus\Desktop\potrace-1.11.win64\kruz.bmp");
bmp2.Save(writer.BaseStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
potrace.StandardInput.WriteLine(); //Without this line the input to Potrace won't go through.
 * **/
potrace.WaitForExit();
```